# IllegalStateException at ActivityManagerProxy.stopServiceToken

Tags: android, crash-reports, intentservice

anybody, please help me to solve the below `Exception`.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:496)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.stopServiceToken (ActivityManagerNative.java:4134)
at android.app.Service.stopSelf (Service.java:567)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage (IntentService.java:66)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is Google crash report, occurred in Samsung Tab E and **LG K4**. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: crash log is not complete

Comment: I have only this much, this is from google report.

Comment: this  is not enough to tell what is the reason as it is too broad to tell what may be the real reason since illegalstateexception can happen many conditions

Comment: Yeah... that's why I stuck..

Comment: @AkshayKumarS try to change `No Filters` in `LogCat` after error may be you got some more error logs

Comment: @ND1010_ This is not reproduced in development end.